# Start uTorrent when Windows Starts without the need to logon

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, bittorrent, utorrent

I need to make uTorrent start when Windows Starts only, without the need to logon!
I mean by making uTorrent start, is that uTorrent run and starts downloading in the background without the need to user logon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create new task in the `Task Scheduler`.  Make it run under your account, provide it with password so it can run without login. Schedule it upon startup and point it to the uTorrent executable.

Comment: Now I'm successfully able to make uTorrent run on start up whether the user is logged on or not via `Task Scheduler`. But what is just missing now is to make uTorrent start downloading uncompleted downloads automatically after running!

Comment: @omareg94 that shouldn't be a problem, if you won't manually stop the torrents the uTorrent will start downloading them next time you start the uTorrent.

Comment: There's a problem! When uTorrent starts at system startup, it runs in the background. When I login my user account and run uTorrent, I find that two separate instances (processes) of uTorrent are running. How could I solve this conflict?

Comment: Remove Utorrent from user's startup folder. So you'll have only one instance running under `System` username.